# Unable to debug Javascript in browser

Tags: javascript, javascript-debugger

I am trying to debug through some JS code in firefox. When I click on a certain file (`CometdWorkerJs.js`) in console, that file does not open in Debugger-Sources tab, but rather opens as raw text file. Other files open normally in Debugger-Sources tab. Due to this, I'm unable to debug through this file CometdWorkerJs.js. I've also observed the same behaviour in other browsers like Chrome.

Why does this happen? Is there a way to debug through this file ?

Screen recording of my browser's inspect window -

[image: Screen Recording]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this. The code I was trying to debug is being executed inside a web worker. In chrome, the same can be debugged in `chrome://inspect/#workers`.